# Managed package: Global instance method inside Global class isn't visible?

Tags: apex, managed-package

So I have my global class

```
global without sharing class PaymentUtils {
    global void refreshFromProvider(id recordId) {
    ...
    }
    
    global Payment_Transaction__c createAndStoreSession(
        decimal amount,
        id paymentId,
        String successURL,
        String cancelURL,
        String currencyISO,
        String customerEmail,
        String storageOption
    ) {
    ...
    }
}
```

When I instantiate this class, I can use any of the other global methods (not shown), just not the refreshFromProvider method. Does ANYONE have a clue as to why?

```
utils.createAndStoreSession(20.0, obj.id, '','','','');//works fine
utils.refreshFromProvider(obj.id); //fails with Method is not visible: void namespace.PaymentUtils.refreshFromProvider(Id)
```

I am tearing my hair out trying to spot what's different. there are other void methods i can use, there are other single input methods that work too!

Comment: I should add, this is in the org where the package is installed. everything else works so there is something special happening here, I just don't know how to refresh or whatever it is that's providing this... odd behaviour.

Comment: I'd repackage triple checking that  version of this class that goes into the package has that method...

Comment: trying to build a new one now (I updated the API version on a bunch of other classes too), Now salesforce decides it's a good time to consider whether or not it wants to make the package available haha! I will report back afterwards!

Comment: Also, when we talk about the version, each Apex class has a specific [Package Version](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_version_settings_packages.htm) in addition to its own API version.

Comment: the package version specified for that class was indeed the issue. the newer versions weren't being used by my calling class. Setup > Apex Classes >{classnamehere} >edit > Version settings

Thanks all!

Comment: @mike - welcome, FYI you can [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) your own question (and eventually accept it) to help others. That's the sign something is solved vs. adding it to your question title.

Comment: There's an answer, below. Instead of adding "SOLVED" to the title you should mark the answer as best and (if you are permitted, you require reputation to do that) upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

When a new Apex class is created or it is an existing class and a new package is installed the class takes a dependency on the package version at the time.
This dictates what functionality from the managed package the Apex class can see, including global methods.

For example, if the package was a v1.0 that the class was created against and a v1.1 where the new global method was added, then the Apex class can't see that method.

These settings are controlled by the [Package Version](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_version_settings_packages.htm) settings. See also [Managing Version Settings for Apex](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_version_settings_apex.htm&type=5)

It will look something like this 10 year old screenshot from [my blog](https://www.fishofprey.com/2012/05/salesforce-referencing-installed.html)
[image]

You can also see this in the [Metadata API for an ApexClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_classes.htm) via the packageVersions.